# How to call a method in PyQt5 right after the interface is done loading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am making an instrument interface in Qt5 and it works fine. The only issue is that it's slow to start because the interface `__init__` contains a time-consuming method (5-10 seconds) used to connect to the instrument. Currently, nothing shows up for several seconds then the whole interface shows up with the "successfully connected to the instrument" message already written in its console (a textEdit widget).

What I would like is **to have the interface show up instantly, and only after it's shown it should start the communication protocol.** I am sure this is just a matter of moving one line around, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a minimal example of the program structure:

```
# ================================================
#      Interface management.
# ================================================

class RENAMEMELATER(Ui_renamemetoo, QObject):

     def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Ui_renamemetoo, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_renamemetoo()
        self.ui.setupUi(parent)

        # Redirect IDE console towards GUI console.
        sys.stdout = EmittingStream()
        sys.stdout.textWritten.connect(self.redirect_console_messages)
        sys.stderr = EmittingStream()
        sys.stderr.textWritten.connect(self.redirect_console_messages)

        # Initialize PC/instrument communication (MOVE SOMEWHERE ELSE?)
        self.T = TaborSE5082("USB0::0x168C::0x5082::0000218391::INSTR") # TIME CONSUMING.



   def redirect_console_messages(self, text):
       """All print() from the program are appended on a textEdit
          instead of the IDE console."""

        self.ui.Console_textEdit.append(text.rstrip("\n"))



    def close_program(self):
        """Call those functions after the user clicked on exit."""

        self.T.CLOSE()
        sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
        sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
        print("Program terminated.")

# ================================================
#      Program execution.
# ================================================

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Define the app.
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()

    # Start the interface.
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    prog = RENAMEMELATER(Form)
    Form.show()

    # Handle what happens at program exit.
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(prog.close_program)

    # Launch.
    app.exec()
```

In the main I can use `app.aboutToQuit` to close the instrument. Maybe there is some sort of `app.isDoneLoading` that I could `.connect` to my instrument initialization in the same way?

Thank you.

Comment: share yout Ui_renamemetoo class

Comment: try with: `import threading` `...` `threading.Thread(targer=TaborSE5082, args=("USB0::0x168C::0x5082::0000218391::INSTR", ) daemon=True ).start()`

Comment: The Ui is generated automatically, I'll try to clean it up and share it after I tested the threading solution.

Comment: Do you update the GUI using the data of variable self.T?

Comment: Yes, the textEdit console gets a few lines appended to it while the `self.T` (the instrument) works.

Comment: The threading worked nicely, thanks a lot for your solution!

Comment: Surely. I will also have to modify the class a tiny bit so that the instance of class TaborSE5082 is returned. Currently it does start its __init__ in a new thread and speeds up things but then we can't access the object anymore.

Comment: Look at my updated code, you can access the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A task that takes 5 to 10 seconds is heavy so apart from not showing the GUI you can freeze it so the solution is to run it in another thread:

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    # ...
    threading.Thread(target=self.callback, daemon=True).start()

def callback(self):
    self.T = TaborSE5082("USB0::0x168C::0x5082::0000218391::INSTR")
    # another code
```